# Caesar Cipher C++ (arrays and pointers)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, caesar-cipher

I am a complete beginner with c++ and up to this point in school we have only learned and used Java. Our first project this year is to create a caesar cipher but we must use the header file provided by our professor. At this point I am only trying to shift the letters and prove my concept before coding the encrypting and decrypting methods. Any help as to what I am doing wrong and why this code isnt compiling would be amazing.

This is our Header file, we are not allowed to make any changes to this file at all:

```
// include file for Caesar cipher code
//

#ifndef CAESAR_H
#define CAESAR_H

#include <string>

class Caesar {

private:
    //pointers used to refer to the standard alphabet array and the Caesar shift array
    char* std_alphabet;
    char* c_alphabet;

public:
    // The constructor . . . 
    // create the two arrays with the c_alphabet array contents representing the std_alphabet 
    // characters shifted by a value of the shift parameter
    Caesar(int shift = 0);

    // encrypt a message. Returns count of characters processed
    // first string is message, second is encrypted string
    int encrypt(const std::string& message, std::string& emessage);

    // decrypt a message. Returns count of characters processed
    // first string is encrypted string, second is decrypted string
    int decrypt(const std::string& message, std::string& dmessage);

    //delete any memory resources used by the class
    ~Caesar();

}; // end of class . . .
#endif
```

This is my .cpp file, I am only in the stage of currently trying to shift my alphabet in an array but I do not understand why my header file is using pointers or if I am creating my arrays properly(I was able to get this concept to work in a separate file but not using the header file).  I am only trying to print the lines to make sure this works before going forward with any coding:

```
#ifndef CAESAR_C
#define CAESAR_C

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Caesar.h"

using namespace std;

int shift, i, k;
char letter = 'a';

Caesar::Caesar(const int n) {

    shift = n;
    std_alphabet[26];
    c_alphabet[26];

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        std_alphabet[i] = letter;
        letter++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        cout << std_alphabet[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        k = (i + shift) % 26;
        c_alphabet[i] = std_alphabet[k];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

        cout << c_alphabet[i] << " ";
    }


};
#endif
```

This is my test file, I dont really know how to initiate a Caesar object properly.  Like I said I am a complete beginner with c++ and would greatly appreciate any directions:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Caesar.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Caesar* test = new Caesar(5);

    cout << test;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: If it helps, your teacher doesn't seem much better. ... Nonetheless, as it is now, it seems like you're asking if someone could do your homework.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not really a good question for this site I'm afraid.  I suggest you take the tour (in help), think about reading one of [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and come back when you have a good question which is capable of a definitive answer.

Comment: I am not asking for someone to do my homework I am asking what I am I doing wrong in my current code to get it to compile.....  All I want to see is my alphabet shift in my cout in my test, thats all my code is currently trying to do.

Comment: Could you add the error messages?

Comment: For the purposes of asking on Stack Overflow, you can *and should* change the header file.  You don't need the comments, and you don't need one of the encrypt/decrypt functions.  Try and reduce your problem to a [mcve] and include the errors, and *that* will be a good question.  (Although you may well find the problem becomes clear when you do that.)

Comment: This `char* std_alphabet;` is not initialized by this `std_alphabet[26];`.

Comment: Thanks manni66, thats where I knew I had an issue but I dont really know how to initialize the pointer in my .cpp file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Please don't mind if my answer is vague since I'm quite new to participating in stackoverflow

It seems like you have not done much research on the issue or even tried to figure out the solution yourself before asking this question. But anyway I'll just try to be helpful to you.


Do these first (I guess already know these things):

- First of all ofcourse, save your header and cpp files as Caesar.h and Caesar.cpp, respectively, and test.cpp maybe the test file.

  Then include the header 'stdlib.h' in your test file since you're using the function system().

  Then compile ur program using the command ***g++ Caesar.cpp test.cpp -o test*** and run it.


  Now, the main issue with ur code is at the line ***cout << test;***. 
  You have to overload the operator '<<' for the class 'Caesar' first which will print the values in the private member variables ***std_alphabet*** and ***c_alphabet***. I suggest you take a tour of this page http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-stream-insertion-operators-c/
  Moreover, the design strategy of the class 'Ceasar' is not satisfactory. I mean the variable 'shift' in 'Caesar.cpp' should have been a private member variable of the class 'Caesar' which makes more sense. Anyway those are just OOP concerns.
  One more thing is that the constructor contains two lines: ***std_alphabet[26]*** and ***c_alphabet[26]***
  Honestly, I don't know what's that weird syntax but it somehow gets compiled in my system. But that's what causes the program to crash during runtime. So I recommend  just replacing those two lines with
   ***std_alphabet = new char[26];*** and similar for ***c_alphabet***.
  Finally, you just have to define the functions ***encrypt()*** and ***decrypt()*** in the file 'Ceasar.cpp' and I hope you can do that much since it is your assignment :D

   BEST OF LUCK !!!

Comment: Thanks, ya I was getting tripped up on needing the new operator for the arrays.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome dude! I was just trying to be helpful and I hope I did. Good luck with your project again.